# Jquery UI selectmenus are shown below the footer

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a webpage structured in this way:

```
<!doctype html>
<html> 
    <head> ... </head> 
    <body>
        <div id='pagewrap'>
            <nav> ... </nav>
            <div id='content'> ... </div>
            <footer> ... </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

With this CSS:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}

#pagewrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

nav {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
}

#content {
    display: block;
    padding: 35px 3% 80px 3%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: both;
}

footer {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
}
```

Inside `content` I have JqueryUI selectmenus. If the dropdowns are close to the footer, they can be displayed below it. In these cases, I would like the dropdowns to push the footer down, is it possible?

Comment: Make content `height : auto;`

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh Still not working

Comment: remove the position:absolute from footer

Comment: @MarouenMhiri Not working. I believe that the solution implies changing Jquery-UI CSS defaults.

Comment: do you have a fiddle for that or a link where this not works?